# Instal openCV on mac os x 10.6.7 with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Mac (OS X v10.6.3) with this guide : http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/opencv-snow-leopard/

The build failed. This'is the error:

> ld: library not found for -lavcodec
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Where can I found and install this library?

Comment: avcodec is part of ffmpeg library

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the article you have macports installed.

If so use it to install openCV e.g.

```
sudo port install opencv
```

the current macports installs openCV 2.2.0

If you have not used macports for some time you should update it first to get the latest versions see [guide](http://guide.macports.org/#using.common-tasks)

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

Comment: If I try sudo port install opencv:
Portfile changed since last build; discarding previous state.
--->  Installing libiconv @1.14_0+universal
Error: Target org.macports.install returned: /usr/bin/tar: +CONTENTS: Not found in archive
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Log for libiconv is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_libiconv/libiconv/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade cmake failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>

Comment: try `sudo port clean opencv` then `sudo port install opencv` again

Comment: After updating I would also sudo port clean libiconv - as that is your current error - it has not got a complete tar file from somewhere,